# youtube-dl: download a YouTube channel without user ID

Tags: youtube-dl

The youtube-dl `ytuser:<youtube username>` option referred to in this question: [youtube-dl : Downloading a YouTube user's complete video collection](https://superuser.com/questions/917271/youtube-dl-downloading-a-youtube-users-complete-video-collection) requires the user ID. But some YouTube channels do not indicate the user ID, like [this YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCKpIOnsk-gcwHXIzuk24ExA).

How can I download this entire channel?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the youtube-dl `ytuser:<youtube username>` option. I was able to start downloading and download several videos from the channel that you linked to in your question without using that option, but my answer won't work on older versions of youtube-dl. I tested my answer on both an old and a new version of youtube-dl. It worked on the latest version of youtube-dl, but it didn't work on the old version.

Update youtube-dl to the latest version before you start downloading all the videos in a channel.

```
sudo snap install youtube-dl # start with snap run youtube-dl
```

or

```
sudo apt remove youtube-dl  
sudo apt install python-pip   
python3 -m pip install --user youtube-dl
```

If you already have installed youtube-dl with pip, you can update it  to the latest version with this command:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade youtube-dl # omit the sudo if installing in a Python virtual environment
```

Open the terminal and type:

```
youtube-dl -f best -ciw -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" -v <url-of-channel>
```

...where `<url-of-channel>` is replaced by the URL of the channel and replace `FORMAT` with any available video format, for example `18`. To show the available formats of a video type:

```
youtube-dl -F <url-of-video>
```

*Note:* If you are downloading a lot of videos, you should change directories to the directory where you want to save the videos before you start downloading them.

#### Explanation

```
-f, --format FORMAT
    video format code

-c, --continue                   
    force resume of partially downloaded files

-i, --ignore-errors              
    continue on download errors, for example to skip unavailable videos in a channel 

-w, --no-overwrites
    do not overwrite files

-v, --verbose
    print various debugging information
```